# What is size of class while using inheritence?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

Hey I'm trying to understand how size of class work when I'm using inheritance, so I wrote this code:

```
class AA 
{
public :
    int a;
    virtual int getSize() {return sizeof(*this);}   
};

class BB : public AA
{
public :
    int b;  
    virtual int getSize2() {return sizeof(*this);}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AA aa;
    BB bb;
    std::cout << "Class AA : " << aa.getSize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Class BB : " << bb.getSize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Class BB : " << bb.getSize2() << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this code is :

```
Class AA : 8
Class BB : 8
Class BB : 12
```

My question is : why the second output return the size of AA instead than returning the size of BB? bb it's BB type, so I was expecting 12 instead of 8?

Comment: "why is the result blah" is almost always a bad question; a better question would be "My intent was to blah, according to my understanding blah does blah, and then blah follows, but it does not work in practice, how is my reasoning about blah not correct?"

Answer (score 3):

```
virtual int getSize() {return sizeof(*this);}
```

Although we don't always think of it as such, `sizeof` computes its value at compile-time, not run-time. So you might as well think of this function as looking like this:

```
virtual int getSize() {return 8;}
```

Which you would obviously not expect to change when inherited into another class.

The way to ensure that derived classes return the correct value is to make sure they override this function with the size of their respective class.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer which directly addresses OP's issue - `sizeof` computes its value at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Classes have no size. Objects have sizes.
2. getSize() only knows the size of objects of type A.
3. getSize2() only knows the size of objects of type B.

Comment: Types have sizes. `sizeof(AA)` would be legitimate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That just means "size of an object of type `AA`". Doesn't make the type have a size.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sure, I'll grant you that "size of an object T" is equivalent to "size of type T" when talking about c++, but I won't grant you that the second formulation is incorrect. In practice, nobody competent would be confused by the statement "`int` has a size of 4 on my platform" which is more concise than "variables of type `int` have a size of 4 on my platform". When describing a type, the size is a ubiquitous characteristic, rather or not it's explicitly recognized by the standard. Correcting someone for using the first formulation is, I believe, needlessly pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

You never override `getSize()` in `BB` so `bb.getSize()` calls `AA::getSize()` and returns the size of `bb`'s `AA` part.  To get the behavior you expected you need to add

```
int getSize() {return sizeof(*this);}
```

in `BB`.

---

To get into more detail when you do

```
bb.getSize()
```

That gets translated to `BB::getSzie(bb)`.  So we call `BB`'s function `getSzie()` and we pass it the object to use.  Since `BB` doesn't override `getSize()` the function that is chosen is `AA::getSize()`.  So we pass the `bb` to `AA`'s function.  `AA`'s version of the function takes a `AA&` so in the function `this` has the type `AA` even though we gave it a `BB`.  That is why it prints the size of `AA`.  You have to add the override into `BB` so that when it call the function the static type of `this` is `BB` and then you can get `BB`'s size.

Comment: you answer does not explain **why**. The answer I linked to (as I believe this one is be direct duplicate of) gives much more information OP looks for.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski How do I not explain why `bb.getSize()` returns the same as `aa.getSize()`.  I don't see how your question that you suggest as a dupe is a dupe for this question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl *"The reason being that the function operates on an instance of `AA`."* - That's not true, the type of `*this` is still `BB`, and if you where to call virtual function from `getSize()`, you would call `BB`'s override, the real reason is that `sizeof()` is a compile-time value, and at compile time `decltype(*this)` inside `getSize()` is `AA&`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Added a more in-depth explanation.